# Multiple terminal handling in python

Tags: python, linux, process, terminal

I have a python application which i want to purpose as a multi as a multi terminal handler, i want each object to have it's own terminal separated from the rest each running it's own instance, exactly like when i run two or more separate terminals in Linux (/bin/sh or /bin/bash)

sample: (just logic not code)

```
first_terminal = terminalInstance()
second_terminal = terminalInstance()
first_result = first_terminal.doSomething("command")
second_result = second_terminal.doSomething("command")
```

i actually need to have each terminal to grab a stdin & stdout in a virtual environment and control them, this is why they must be seperate, is this possible in python range? i've seen alot of codes handling a single terminal but how do you do it with multiple terminals.
PS i don't want to include while loops (if possible) since i want to add scalability from dealing with 2 or more terminals to as much as my system can handle? is it possible to control them by reference giving each terminal a reference and then calling on that object and issuing a command?

Answer (score 0):

The `pexpect` module (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pexpect/), among others, allows you to launch programs via a pseudo-tty, which "allows your script to spawn a child application and control it as if a human were typing commands."

You can easily spawn multiple commands, each running in a separate pseudo-tty and represented by a separate object, and you can interact with each object separately. There is a lot of flexibility as to when/how you interact. You can send input to them, and read their output, either blocking or non-blocking, and incorporating timeouts and alternative outputs.

Here's a trivial session example (run bash, have it execute an "ls" command, gather the first line of output).

```
import pexpect
x = pexpect.spawn("/bin/bash")
x.sendline("ls")
x.expect("\n")  # End of echoed command
x.expect("\n")  # End of first line of output
print x.before  # Print first line of output
```

Note that you'll receive *all* the output from the terminal, typically including an echoed copy of every character you send to it. If running something like a shell, you might also need to set the shell prompt (or determine the shell prompt in use) and use that in parsing the output (i.e. in finding the end of each command's output).

Comment: does this work with randomly inputed commands? read by input()?

Comment: I think so. But it's not clear what your concern is. What difference does it make where the command comes from?

Comment: expect means what exactly? doesn't it mean i'm expecting a certain output from the system?

Comment: Yes. But that can be something as simple as the next shell prompt or even just a newline. Also, you can use a time-out and get the output that's been produced up until that instant.